# How to model not in with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Let's say I have a row with a cell called 'version' which holds the current version of the row.

This version number will be the same for a lot of rows.

At some point I want to find all rows with a version not equal to some given version like: give me all rows with a version != 1.0, and I get back all rows with versions 0.9, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.7.1.2 and so on (in my use case I will only search for 'older' versions).

I'd love to get some input on how to model this.

br, Svante

Answer (score 0):

You can have your version column as a second part of your primary key (id, version) and then you can query it by select * from  where id = x and version < '1.0';

Comment: This won't solve his problem. He needs to find ALL rows with a version different from a specific value. With your model you can't get all rows, you need to know the partition key

Comment: yes. its not a exact solution. But its the closest solution achievable in cassandra as per my knowledge. The key is: to make a non equal operations on a column, that column should be a clustering column!! Based on the table definition you have to redefine to achieve it.

Comment: In a composite primary key the first element is known as partition key. Imagine you have the car name as partition key and the car color as clustering key. You would be able to query for all cars with a given name and for all cars with a given name and a specific color but you won't be able to query all cars of a specific color. Now replace the car name with the row identifier and car color with what you call version. You won't be able to query for version unless you know the row identifier

Comment: Yes, sorry for being unclear. What I mean is, in this case I don't know the partition key when creating the query.

Comment: The solution I offered you in the next message is a way to handle this cassandra miss putting some more logic in the application. It's fast in retrieving data and you can create versions history easily: for each new version V you read the set of the V-1 entry, you add "V-1" to this set and you write into V. If you find better solutions let us know. HTH, Carlo

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this in Cassandra.
Depending on the situation you can create workarounds in your applications and/or use "IN" clause. What I'd do is creating a table containing, for each version, a set of the "previous versions".

```
 create table version_history (version float PRIMARY KEY , previous set<float>);
```

Anytime you need to get "all the rows with a version previous to X", I'd query version_history to retrieve the set and then make a query like

```
select * from rowcontainer where version in (previous[1], previous[2] ... previous[n]));
```

It's just an idea, you need to perform always 2 queries but this is surely better than scanning the whole table.

HTH,
Carlo